# Unwind Segues not working on Xcode 6

Tags: ios

I just downloaded Xcode 6.0.1, and I tried running my app in the simulator. All of my unwind segues are not working. All of my code is in Objective-C, I have NO Swift whatsoever. The segues worked perfectly fine before I updated Xcode.

Am I the only one with this problem?

Comment: Unwind segues work the same way they did in previous versions of Xcode.

Comment: I know that. But then why are my unwind segues not working with the new verison?

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same problem on Xcode 6 GM. All unwind segue calls simply get ignored. I should add this particular project is not using Swift either.

Comment: I also noticed that if you change the original segue from a modal to a push (provided that a navigation controller is present), for example, the unwind segue works as expected.

Comment: @jlehr I'm experiencing issues with unwind segues as well. In Xcode 6.0.1 with base SDK 8.0.1 with an upgraded 5.x project, they do "nothing". That is, when activated non of the callbacks are called, non of any segue related method is called, and no error is issued from the SDK. This issue also show for non-modally presented controllers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE: This has been fixed with the release of iOS 8.1.x**

After a lot of fiddling around with this, my experience is that only view controllers presented modally are affected by this issue. The work around in this case is to set your segue presentation to `Current Context` instead of `Default`.

Credit to this SO poster https://stackoverflow.com/a/25842508/401092

Comment: Nice, is there any solution if you can't use Current Context? I'm using Over Full Screen to work around a different issue.

Comment: Ok, that's sweet. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug affecting iOS 8.0(and .1 and .2) - view controllers presented modally wouldn't perform unwind segues - the unwind method wouldn't be called.

This issue appears to be fully resolved with iOS 8.1 beta. Note that iOS 8 doesn't automatically dismiss the modally presented view controller while on iOS 7 it does, so if you need to support both you'll want to detect if it's being dismissed in the unwind method and if it's not then manually dismiss it.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me!

So in my case I had a view controller presented modally and when I wire an unwind segue to a button, the prepareForSegue method was never called and the unwind method in the root controller never called neither.

Change to current context and everything is working.
Thanks