# Modally presented view controller can't unwind

Tags: xcode6, modalviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have a UIViewController sublcass (VC1) embedded in a UINavigationController. VC1 triggers a modal segue to another UIViewController subclass (VC2) which is embedded in its own, different UINavigationController. Inside of an action method triggered by a UIBarButtonItem in VC2's nav bar, I call

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SomeString" sender:nil]`

which corresponds to an unwind method inside VC1. For some reason, the transition does not occur.

It only became a problem after switching to XCode 6. It worked fine in XCode 5. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been doing the rounds and I have the exact same problem. Unfortunately there is no good solution to it yet, other than go back to the old `delegate` pattern.

If you subclass your parent view controller navigation controller and implement `- (UIViewController*)viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction:(SEL)action fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController withSender:(id)sender` you will see that the modal is actually looking for your unwindSegue method on the navigation controller instead of the view controller that presented the modal.

The problem gets even more amplified if you have a container view controller as the method above gets called all the way up the controller chain to the storyboard's initial view controller.

There's a potential workaround here [Unwind Segue not working in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654941/unwind-segue-not-working-in-ios-8/25842508#25842508) but it has its downsides and side effects as well.