# unwind or dismiss view controller not working. Xcode 6.4

Tags: objective-c, unwind-segue, xcode6.4

I've been trying to make my pushed view controller dismiss or go back one once a confirm action has taken place. I read the many posts in stackoverflow on this subject (I've never done it before) e.g:
[How to perform Unwind segue programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509422/how-to-perform-unwind-segue-programmatically)

but had quite some problems. First of all, the ctrl drag from view controller to exit, didn't work though that seems to be a bug in Xcode 6, so I added the following workaround as advised and changed the class back and forth:

```
@interface RequestLessonViewController ()

- (IBAction)unwindToMyViewController: (UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;

@end
```

This allowed me to add in the segue from my action button to Exit. I also of course gave it an identifier (`unwindSegue`).

I then added the `performWithSegueWithIdentifie`r line in my buttons code as follows:

```
- (IBAction)requestLessonAction:(UIButton *)sender {

    // PUT CONFIRM POP UP IN HERE ???
    NSLog(@"ADD A LESSON REQUEST TO LESSONS DATABASE");
    UIAlertView *confRequest = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Lesson Request Submitted"
                                                         message:@"Congratulations"
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [confRequest show];


    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindSegue" sender:self];



}
```

However my unwind is still not being kicked off.

Maybe this is still a problem due to `xcode 6.4` and I need to use a different work around?

Anyway any help in this would be great

Thanks

Comment: Hi Kitcc, can you explain how are you pushing this view controller you want to unwind or dismissed using segue in storyboard? is it push or present or custome segue?

Comment: Hi @MuhammadAwais its a Push segue from the previous view controller

Comment: This might be of interest if you're still on Xcode 6.4 - check which OS your running on...! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654941/unwind-segue-not-working-in-ios-8

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this using this very useful and clear github from Bradley.

https://github.com/bradley/iOSUnwindSegueProgramatically

Basically I wasn't creating the following type of method on the viewcontroller I was returning too, but inside the one I was trying to exit from :-/ All clear now thanks.

```
- (IBAction)returnToStepOne:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    NSLog(@"And now we are back.");
}
```