# Unwind segue not working in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have the following view controllers set up: UITabBarController -> UINagivationController -> UIViewController1 -> UIViewController2

And I'm trying to unwind from UIViewController2 to UIViewController1.

I have the following code in UIViewController1

```
- (IBAction)unwindToVC1:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue {
}
```

To set up the link in the Storyboard, I went to UIViewController2, and control-dragged from a button I created to the exit symbol at the top, and selected the method `unwindtoVC1:` from the list presented. Then I launch the app and click the button but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Here is what my storyboard looks like
[image: Storyboard]

EDIT: I found the error. It was an oversight on my part in not assigning the correct custom class to UIViewController1.

Comment: Are you using segue only while pushing from ViewController1 to ViewController 2?

Comment: Yes I'm using a show segue to go from ViewController1 to ViewController 2

Comment: It looks really strange. From the picture I can see that "unWindToDailyMeals". Can you double check you have done the exactly same procedure you have explained?

Comment: Please check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654941/unwind-segue-not-working-in-ios-8

Comment: Put unwindSegue method in creating custom TabbarViewController

Comment: I've seen that link but according to the answer, the bug should've been fixed in iOS 8?

Comment: Okay, I figured out the issue. My ViewController1 was not assigned as the custom View Controller class I had.

Comment: That's Cool @Rennir